# I need an element in a JavaScript form (in React) for selecting several items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, react-component, jsform

I’m building a React app dedicated to adventures and countries

I need some ideas concerning the form element I have to use for achieving a multiple selection

I’m currently building the component where the user can create activities, I’m almost done with it but there’s one thing that I don’t know how to tackle

It’s very simple, the user should be able to create multiple activities at once, simply by indicating several countries where the activity type will be held

For instance, if I create the skiing activity, and I indicate 3 countries, then 3 activities should be created.

I’m using a Form (a controlled form), the question is, how could I let the user select several countries, while letting the user know what countries are currently selected

So far, the form has the following look:

[image]

The countries come from a database, there could be many of them, and I’m loading a bunch of them in a cache in memory (an array of objects)
I’ll appreciate your valuable hints

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: [`<select>` has a `multiple` attribute.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)  Aside from that, if you're looking for recommendations for plugins/libraries with styled and feature-rich components, such recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: you may consider to use some UI libraries, such as Material-UI. see this example: https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#multiple-select